# change color in substring in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin-android-extensions

I want to make "show more" in different colors but, it's not working using spannable in kotlin.
please help.

```
                val mSpannableString = SpannableString("show more")
                val mBlue = ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE)
                mSpannableString.setSpan(mBlue,2,7,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

                holder.MORE.text = "READ MORE"
                if (Expert_answer.length>=300) {

                    holder.description.text = Expert_answer.substring(0,300)+"..."+mSpannableString
                }else{
                    holder.description.text = Expert_answer
                }
```

Comment: please ask me anything related to this question

Comment: `val mBlue = ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK)` so if you want it to be blue why are you using black?

Comment: just find how `setSpan` is used in java and convert it to kotlin, there is tons of examples on the net, one minute googling: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spans (btw they have both kotlin and java samples)

Comment: I can do it in java , but not working in kotlin. also, if any link you can share me that will be very helpful thanks.

Comment: i gave you a link, it has both kotlin and java  samples

Comment: I'm a newbie in kotlin

Comment: Do you want show more to be added after 300 characters only?

Comment: thanks for helping "pskink".Also, how do You find these guide show easily i was searching hours for that in the guide.

Comment: your welcome, i just asked mr google for: `android setspan` and it was the 3rd result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have done this so I may be able to help you here.

```
   val txtShow ="show"
   val txtMore ="More"
   val spannable = SpannableString(txtShow) // String for which you want to change the color
   spannable.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, txtShow.length, 
   Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
   txtMessage.text = TextUtils.concat(txtShow,txtMore)
```

Let me know if still any help require or stuck.Happy Coding!!!

Comment: I was concating string using "+" only before loading to TextView , but using TextUtils.concat solve the problems thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a custom implementation for the span as following.

```
 val spannable = SpannableStringBuilder(“Text is spantastic!”)
spannable.setSpan(
     ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 
     8, 12, 
     Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
```

For Your example here

```
 val showMore = "show more"
        val Expert_answer =
            "sample text  sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text "

        val Expert_answer =Expert_answer.substring(0, 30) + "..." + showmore
        val mSpannableString = SpannableStringBuilder(Expert_answer)

        val mBlue = ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE)
        mSpannableString.setSpan(mBlue, 33, 42, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

        abcTitle.text = mSpannableString
```

[image]

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

Below function will substring `input` to 300 characters (if it exceeds 300 chars), append "Show more" to the end of it and set value to `holder.description.text`

```
private fun setShowMoreIfNeeded(input: String) {
    val maxLenthOfStingShown = 300
    holder.description.text = if (input.length > maxLenthOfStingShown) {
        SpannableStringBuilder()
            .append(input.substring(0, maxLenthOfStingShown))
            .color(Color.BLUE) {append("Show more")}
    } else {
        input
    }
}
```